# How to set type of a property in javascript object, like mongoose schema design do.?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying setting type for a key of an object in javascript.
    var obj ={};
    obj.name = string;
    obj.age = number;
    obj.approve = false;
it is more like designing mongoose schema. eg.

```
var mongo = require('mongoose');
var mySchema = new mongo.Schema({
"name":{type: String},
"version":{type: String},
"author":{type:String}
});
```

so that while saving object mongoose check the type.
How can i perform this functionality with normal javascript object while declaring it. so that i can perform type checking for incoming API request for an object. 
I hope you all understand what i want to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain using a example maybe, a simpler one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSON schema validator, like following:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv

Short example:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = Ajv();
var schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "number" },
    "bar": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": [ "foo", "bar" ]
};

var data = { "foo": 1 };

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

console.log(validate(data)); // false
```